# Returning aggregate results on a Lightning component

Tags: soql, lightning

I have built a lightning page where I want to display summarized data from a aggregate apex method. my method has some return value problem.
this is my method and I want to return Ass and Credits

```
public class OutstandingCreditAuraController {
@AuraEnabled
    public static List<Assessment_Schedule__c> getOutstandingCredits(){

       List<AggregateResult> agrResults = [Select Assessor_name__c ass, Sum(Credits__c) credits
                    from Assessment_Schedule__c where 
                    (TEC_Status__c = 'Active' OR TEC_Status__c = 'On Hold') and                 
                    (Company__c = 'CityFitness HO') group by Assessor_name__c];


        for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults){
            return((decimal)ar.get('credits'));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based purely on some Googling (where I didn't find `AggregateResult` mentioned as a type that can be returned), I think defining your own class to return will work:

```
public class OutstandingCreditAuraController {

    public OutstandingCredit {
        @AuraEnabled public String name {get; set;}
        @AuraEnabled public Integer credits {get; set;}
        OutstandingCredit(String name, Integer credits) {
            this.name = name;
            this.credits = credits;
        }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<OutstandingCredit> getOutstandingCredits(){

        List<AggregateResult> agrResults = [
                Select Assessor_name__c ass, Sum(Credits__c) credits
                from Assessment_Schedule__c
                where (TEC_Status__c = 'Active' OR TEC_Status__c = 'On Hold')
                and (Company__c = 'CityFitness HO')
                group by Assessor_name__c
                ];

        List<OutstandingCredit> results = new List<OutstandingCredit>();
        for (AggregateResult ar: agrResults){
            results.add(new OutstandingCredit(
                    (String) ar.get('ass'),
                    (Integer) ar.get('credits')
                    ));
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```

But others with practical experience may have a neater approach to offer e.g. perhaps a simple `Map` can be returned.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to return a `List<AggregateResult>` directly, no need to return a list of wrapper types. Your original post is likely failing because you're trying to return a single `AggregateResult` when the return type you have specified for your method is `List<Assessment_Schedule__c>`. So try something like this:

```
public class OutstandingCreditAuraController {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<AggregateResult> getOutstandingCredits() {
       return [
           SELECT Assessor_name__c ass, SUM(Credits__c) credits
           FROM Assessment_Schedule__c 
           WHERE (TEC_Status__c = 'Active' OR TEC_Status__c = 'On Hold') AND                 
               (Company__c = 'CityFitness HO') 
           GROUP BY Assessor_name__c
       ];
    }

}
```